# Emulator database onUpdate update.after.ref incorrect

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I use the emulator for functions and realtime database, and have a test `onUpdate` function attached to a secondary database (not the default one).

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const ref = admin.app().database("https://non-default-database.firebaseio.com").ref();
exports.test = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .database.instance("non-default-database")
  .ref("test/test")
  .onUpdate(async (update) => {
    let before = update.before.val();
    let after = update.after.val();
    console.log(`Beforeval: ${before} .:. Afterval: ${after}`);
    console.log(update.after.ref.toString());
    if (after !== before) { //avoid infinite loop
      console.log(
        "Before set: ",
        (await update.after.ref.once("value")).val(),
        (await ref.child(`test/test`).once("value")).val()
      );
      await update.after.ref.set(false);
      console.log(
        "After set: ",
        (await update.after.ref.once("value")).val(),
        (await ref.child(`test/test`).once("value")).val()
      );
    }
  });
```

Yes, all the function does is set the value it is attached to to `false`, and spew some info to the console.
If the value at 'test/test' equals `false` to begin with and we set it to `true`, this is the console output:

```
Beforeval: false .:. Afterval: true
http://localhost:9000/test/test
Before set:  false true
After set:  false false
```

1. In the first line we can see that the values before and after are what we expect.
2. The second output line seems okay, but it looks like it is missing `?ns=non-default-database` (first hint).
3. The third line should be the value as read from the database before setting. First using the `update.after.ref` reference and second using the root reference of the secondary database. We would expect both to return `true` since we just set it to be `true`. However, the first one is `false` (second hint).
4. The fourth and last line gives us the same as the previous one but after setting. Here we do get what we expect again.

When we look at the database, the value is still `true`.

Now let's change the function to not set it to `false` but to the string `foobar`, thus `await update.after.ref.set(false);` becomes `await update.after.ref.set("foobar");` and let's look at the console output when we change the value from `false` to `true` again:

```
Beforeval: false .:. Afterval: true
http://localhost:9000/test/test
Before set:  false true
After set:  foobar true
```

The first three lines are the same, but hey, look at the fourth line!
The value when reading from `update.after.ref` is indeed set to the string `foobar`, but the value when reading from the root ref is still `true` (third hint).
When we look in the database webpage of the emulator we see that the value is still `true`.
Something else did change, there is a new database (that we probably missed before) named 'fake-server' that I never made. That database is completely empty though (fourth hint).

Okay let's look at the values using the REST API.

- Going to `http://localhost:9000/test/test.json` gives us `null`.
- Going to `http://localhost:9000/test/test.json?ns=non-default-database` gives us `true`.
- Going to `http://localhost:9000/test/test.json?ns=fake-server` gives us `null`.

If we change `await update.after.ref.set(false);` to `await ref.child('test/test').set(false);` it does all work perfectly.

My conclusion from all of this is that when using a secondary server and emulating triggers on those, the `update` variable passed in by `onUpdate` forgets to use that second database, uses some non-existing one, which in some way makes the fake-server database appear but doesn't reference the secondary database.

Comment: For completeness: I am using node.js v12.22.0 and firebase-tools v9.8.0 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: After looking to your post it is possible that .instance() is being ignored and that is why it is the non-existing one as you say.

Researching for a while I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2506) that solve the issue of not trigger the function in a secondary RTDB.

Hopes this helps you

Comment: Nice, thanks for the research and find @Robertocd_98 !

Comment: If this was useful to I will post this as an answer so the people can see it easily, waiting for your reply.